# xsl-fo, org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-body" is missing child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I've got an XML input file lets say `shipnote.xml` which contains a part item list. The part-items have usual attributes `qty`, `partno` and `label`. Each item is assigned to a `packetno`.

I wrote an xsl-file to generate a pdf-shipnote from this data. The requirement is, that every `packetno` shall start with a new page in the pdf-document. Per page there are maximum 5 items.

What I tried to do is, first to select the different `PCKNO`s and loop over this different `packetno`s. Then I embedded a second loop inside the first to retrieve the articles per `PCKNO`, to print them on the shipnote.

Following you can see sample data from ship.xml:

```
root>
 items>

 item PCKNO="1" PCKCNT="2" > QTY>2/QTY> PARTNO>1518/PARTNO> LABEL>Part12/LABEL> /item>
 item PCKNO="1" PCKCNT="2" > QTY>1/QTY> PARTNO>1519/PARTNO> LABEL>Partxy/LABEL> /item>
 item PCKNO="2" PCKCNT="2" > QTY>3/QTY> PARTNO>1518/PARTNO> LABEL>Part12/LABEL> /item>
 item PCKNO="2" PCKCNT="2" > QTY>2/QTY> PARTNO>1519/PARTNO> LABEL>Partxy/LABEL> /item>

 /items>

/root>
```

This layout is required:

```
pdf-Page 1, <b>PCKNO:</b> 1
qty | Partno | Label    |  
----|--------|----------| 
2   | 1518   | Part123  | 
1   | 1519   | Partxyz  | 

pdf-Page 2, <b>PCKNO:</b> 2
qty | Partno | Label    | 
----|--------|----------|
3   | 1518   | Part123  |
2   | 1520   | Partfour |
```

Then I applied the xsl-stylesheet to meet the requirement.

The outer Loop is done with:

```
fo:table table-layout='fixed' width="100%" >
    !-- Columns of shipnote-->
    fo:table-column />
    fo:table-column />
    fo:table-column />
    fo:table-header >
        fo:table-row >
            fo:table-cell><fo:block font-weight="bold">Qty /fo:block>    /fo:table-cell>
            fo:table-cell><fo:block font-weight="bold">Partno. /fo:block> /fo:table-cell>
            fo:table-cell><fo:block font-weight="bold">Partname /fo:block> /fo:table-cell>
        /fo:table-row >
    /fo:table-header>

    fo:table-body>

 !-- outer Loop get distinct pckno-->
xsl:for-each select="items/item[not(@PCKNO=preceding-sibling::position/@PCKNO)]/@PCKNO"
 xsl:variable name="packno" select="."/>    
 !-- inner loop get items per pckno-->
 xsl:for-each select="items/item[@PCKNO = $packno]" >   

    fo:table-row keep-together="always">
        !-- paximum of 5 parts per page-->
        xsl:if test="position() mod 5 = 1">
            xsl:attribute name="break-before">page/xsl:attribute>
        /xsl:if> 
        fo:table-cell>fo:block> xsl:value-of select="QTY"/> /fo:block> /fo:table-cell>
        fo:table-cell>fo:block> xsl:value-of select="PARTNO"/> /fo:block> /fo:table-cell>
        fo:table-cell>fo:block> xsl:value-of select="LABEL"/> /fo:block> /fo:table-cell>
    /fo:table-row>   

 /xsl:for-each>

/xsl:for-each>
```

I'm using this fop command: `fop -xsl shiptest.xsl -xml shiptest.xml -pdf shiptest.pdf`

Result is:

```
     Exception

 - org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: <b>org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-body" is missing child elements. </b>Required content model: marker* (table-row+|table-cell+) (no contextinfo available)

 - javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: <b>org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-body" is missing child elements. </b>Required content model: marker* (table-row+|table-cell+) (no contextinfo available)
```

When I strip the outer loop and use only the inner loop with a constant parameter 1, 2, it works as desired:

```
  xsl:for-each select="items/item[@PCKNO = <b>1</b>]"   /xsl:for-each
  xsl:for-each select="items/item[@PCKNO = <b>2</b>]"   /xsl:for-each
```

But I need it dynamic. I am stuck at this point. Please give me a hint how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is the **xsl:for-each** you are having trouble with....

```
<xsl:for-each select="items/item[not(@PCKNO=preceding-sibling::position/@PCKNO)]/@PCKNO">
```

There are two problems with this...

1. You are doing `preceding-sibling::position`, but there is not element names **position** in your XML.
2. You are selecting the **@PCKNO** attribute in your **xsl:for-each** meaning the inner **xsl:for-each** will be relative to that attribute. But your inner **xsl:for-each** is selecting **items/item**, and so it will not select anything.

So, the 'easiest' fix is to change the first **xsl:for-each** to this

```
<xsl:for-each select="items/item[not(@PCKNO=preceding-sibling::item/@PCKNO)]">
```

So, at this point you are positioned on an **item** element. Therefore, you need to change the inner **xsl:for-each** to this, so it goes back to the parent element, and can then select all the **item** elements with the same **@PCKNO** attribute.

```
<xsl:for-each select="../item[@PCKNO = $packno]">
```

It is worth noting that using **preceding-sibling** isnot a particular efficient way to look for distinct elements. In XLST 1.0, the most efficient way to do grouping is use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Alternatively, if you are able to use XSLT 2.0, you could use **xsl:for-each-group**.

Comment: And you should add a test in the future surrounding the whole table in case nothing meets your loop rows. This would avoid any possible errors in the future for empty table bodies.